# I am writing a code to click on upload button and using AppleScript to upload the file(image/video)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, applescript, page-factory

the web sight has the storage to store the file. my senior is to click on upload button upload the file using AppleScript and use the uploaded file

```
public select_uploded_image AddContent() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String FilePath = "/Users/apple/Documents/360_a.jpg";

    AddVRcontent.click();
    upload.click();
    Thread.sleep(60l);
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String applescriptCommand = "tell app\"System Events\"\n"+
    "keystroke\"G\"using{Command down,Shift down}\n"+
    "delay 2\n"+
    "keystroke\""+FilePath+"\"\n"+
    "delay 1\n"+
    "keystroke return\n"+
    "delay 1\n"+
    "keystroke return\n"+
    "end tell";
    String[]args = {"osascript","-e",applescriptCommand};
    Process process = runtime.exec(args);

    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,select_uploded_image.class); 


}
```

this is failing if the file already exist

Comment: any specific reason for writing script using applescript?

Comment: No specific reason as it is short n easy

Comment: how to wait till this operation gets over

Comment: have you try direct sending sendkeys on your upload button

Comment: yes i have tried it fails